# columnfilterwidget in Datatables Filter sort issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10 with Columnfilterwidget,

Problem i am facing is 
I have values like 
0,1.44,10,100,100.00,20,20.13

Right now Columnfilterwidget is sorting these values alphabetically

```
0
1.44
10
100
100.00
20
20.13
```

But i want them to be filtered numerically

```
0
1.44
10
20
20.13
100
100.00
```

Like this,

This is what i have tried so far

In Columnfilterwidget.js file

```
          ColumnFilterWidget.prototype.fnDraw = function() {
                    var widget = this;
                    var oDistinctOptions = {};
                    var aDistinctOptions = [];
                    var aData;
                    if ( widget.asFilters.length === 0 ) {
                            // Find distinct column values
                            aData = widget.oDataTable.fnGetColumnData( widget.iColumn );

                            $.each( aData, function( i, sValue ) {
                                    var asValues = widget.sSeparator ? sValue.split( new RegExp( widget.sSeparator ) ) : [ sValue ];
                                    $.each( asValues, function( j, sOption ) {
                                            if ( !oDistinctOptions.hasOwnProperty( sOption ) ) {
                                                    oDistinctOptions[sOption] = true;
                                                    aDistinctOptions.push( sOption );
                                            }
                                    } );
                            } );
                            // Build the menu
                            widget.$Select.empty().append( $( '<option></option>' ).attr( 'value', '' ).text( widget.oColumn.sTitle ) );
//                             aDistinctOptions.sort();
                          aDistinctOptions.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});

                            $.each( aDistinctOptions, function( i, sOption ) {
                                    var sText;
                                    if(sOption==='')
                                            sText = $( '<div> (Blank )</div>' ).text();
                                    else
                                            sText = $( '<div>' + sOption + '</div>' ).text();
                                    widget.$Select.append( $( '<option></option>' ).attr( 'value', sOption ).text( sText ) );
                            } );
                            if ( aDistinctOptions.length > 1 ) {
                                    // Enable the menu
                                    widget.$Select.attr( 'disabled', false );
                            } else {
                                    // One option is not a useful menu, disable it
                                    widget.$Select.attr( 'disabled', true );
                            }
                    }
            };
```

I changed sort function to numeric, but how can i identify the coming value is numeric, also i checked `sValue` values are string, so is there any way i can define Columns i want to numeric.

Also tried setting options oColumnFilterWidgets still it didn't worked.

```
oColumnFilterWidgets: {
        "aiExclude": [ 0, 1, 10 ],

      "aoColumnDefs": [

//                     { "bSort": false, "sSeparator": " / ", "aiTargets": [ 5 ] },

                    { "fnSort": function( a, b ) { return a-b; }, "aiTargets": [6] },

      {"sType": "numeric", "aiTargets":[6]}
                  ]

        },
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cyberhobo who fixed this issue.

[[https://github.com/cyberhobo/ColumnFilterWidgets/commit/01efef439c557154bad3d61aa00d47285b6d21d6#diff-72250e81389e20ff2fa22ff884fcb6aaR309][1]](https://github.com/cyberhobo/ColumnFilterWidgets/commit/01efef439c557154bad3d61aa00d47285b6d21d6#diff-72250e81389e20ff2fa22ff884fcb6aaR309%5d%5b1%5d)

Just made the changes he highlighted inside plugin  and

```
               "oColumnFilterWidgets": {

                  "aoColumnDefs": [

                     { "bSort": false, "sSeparator": " / ", "aiTargets": [ 2 ] },

                     { "fnSort": function( a, b ) { return a-b; }, "aiTargets": [ 3 ] }

                  ]

               }
```

Hope this helps.